# difference between javascript console and right clicking the browser and selecting inspect?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-console

I am currently developing an angular app and wish to see my scope in the console.
I currently achieve this by typing `angular.element($0).scope()`.

This works when i open the console by right clicking the page, selecting inspect, navigate to the console tab and enter the code above.

however the same line of code does not work when i open the console by using the browser shortcut.

why does this happen and how can i make it so that when i open the browser through a short cut the line of code works ?

Below i have provided screenshots of the console displaying the different outputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5M8R.jpg

I have found a live website where this phenomenon also occurs so you can try it for yourself : https://www.google.com/partners/?hl=nl#a_profile;bdgt=;idtf=3245994249;lang=;locn=;motv=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome stores the history of inspected elements in variables it creates starting with `$0`.  That's why it only works if you select it first in the elements panel.  There are Chrome Dev Tool extensions like [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) that add a panel to your element inspector showing the scope for the selected element that would probably be helpful for you.  Alternately, you can target the element using `angular.element(<SOME_SELECTOR_HERE>).scope()` to get the scope in the console, rather than relying on the inspection history.

Answer (score 0):

`$0` in chrome console means `most recent inspected element`, if you just open the chrome console, you haven't inspected anything. Check: https://willd.me/posts/0-in-chrome-dev-tools